# Mvn Command not found?

Tags: java, maven, installation

I was working on my maven installation and was messing with a few variables to fix an error and now seemed to have lost it altogether.  My PATH variable is set up correctly along with my JAVA_HOME, but I still get

```
-bash: mvn: command not found
```

I tried deleting the maven files and re-downloading them and opening a new terminal, but no luck. Are there any other trouble shooting techniques I can run through to hopefully figure out my problem.   I am running on a Mac.

Comment: This is an issue with your PATH, have you done echo $PATH to make sure it is correct?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah I just checked it and it is a mess.  How do i adjust it accordingly?  I do: export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin:$PATH
and now my path variable looks like this after echo $PATH :/opt/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/contents/home/bin:/usr/Users/shanewilliams/downloads/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin:/usr/system/Library/OpenSSL/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

Comment: Shouldn't the path point to the maven folder, /opt/apache-maven-3.5.4? Also, you have maven twice in your PATH

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well the bin folder contains the mvn key and all.  According to the maven website it is supposed to point to the maven bin.  Either way my path variable is filled with much more pointless stuff that I would like to get rid of for the time being

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about M2_HOME

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Do you know how I could adjust the PATH variable so it will only point to the maven bin and not the other junk

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, having,  `mvn not found`  after installing with sdkman.

If you installed with sdkman, just like me, you may want to execute: `sdk use maven <version>` e.g.:

```
$ sdk use maven 3.6.3
 
 
# Install skman.
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
$ source ~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh

# Check available maven versions:
$ sdk list java
$ sdk list maven

# install desired candidate and version
$ sdk install java 13.0.1-open
$ sdk install gradle
$ sdk install maven
$ sdk install springboot


# Verify Installation by checking versions:
$ java -version
$ gradle -v
$ mvn --version
$ spring --version
```

Comment: Interesting, you say to run `sdk use maven <version>` but then that does not appear in your list of commands...

Comment: In my case, though, what really fixed it was to open a new terminal. The current terminal would not work on its own. It looks like some of the settings were in the `~/.zshrc` file, however.

Answer (score 1):

If it is linux machine and you install directly using yum, then you could find the maven in /usr/local

So you can set the MAVEN_HOME in ~/.bashrc and do source ~/.bashrc to make it permanent.

Do check by $echo MAVEN_HOME and $echo JAVA_HOME

If you get exact path of both, then it will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Check that, don't forguet to restart the machine

[image: Check that, don't forguet to restart the machine]

Comment: Remove M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME just use the C:\..\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin directory to be in PATH nothing else is needed...